# For which positive a this integral is convergent?

Tags: improper-integrals

For which positive $a$ this integral is convergent?

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^{a}+x^{2a}}\mathrm dx$$

I tried splitting it to two integrals (one from $0$ to $1$). I am not sure, but it seems to be convergent for all $a$.

Comment: You are splitting the domain in the right way. Now discuss them separately. Combine the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, splitting the domain is fine. As $x\to 0^+$,
$$\frac{\sin x}{x^{a}+x^{2a}}\sim \frac{x}{x^{a}}=\frac{1}{x^{a-1}}$$
and therefore the integral ove r $$(0,1]$ is convergent if and only if $a-1<1$.

What about the convergence of the integral $[1,+\infty)$?

Note that, by integration by parts,
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^{a}+x^{2a}} dx=\left[\frac{-\cos x}{x^{a}+x^{2a}}\right]_1^\infty -\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos x(ax^{a-1}+2ax^{2a-1})}{(x^{a}+x^{2a})^2} dx$$
and, for $a>0$,
$$\frac{|\cos x|(ax^{a-1}+2ax^{2a-1})}{(x^{a}+x^{2a})^2}
\leq \frac{ax^{a-1}+2ax^{2a-1}}{(x^{a}+x^{2a})^2}\sim \frac{2a}{x^{4a-(2a-1)}}=\frac{2a}{x^{2a+1}}.$$
What may we conclude?